# no interaction in interactive snapshot mode

Tags: jestjs

I use jest 23.2.0 for my current project. If I run `jest  --watchAll` some snapshot tests fail. I press `i` to go to interactive snapshot mode. Some tests are started but the process is finished very very fast and the following message is shown:

```
Interactive Snapshot Result
 › 2 snapshots reviewed, 2 snapshots updated
```

This is usually the message after going through all failing tests. But there was no interaction and also no snapshot files have been changed.

Any ideas?